# Caret position in textarea with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, scope, caret

I am asking myself if I am doing it right. The problem I have is that I want to preserve caret position after AngularJS update textarea value.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-controlle="editorController">
    <button ng-click="addSomeTextAtTheEnd()">Add some text at the end</button>
    <textarea id="editor" ng-model="editor"></textarea>
</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller("editorController", function($scope, $timeout, $window) {

    $scope.editor = "";

    $scope.addSomeTextAtTheEnd = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.editor = $scope.editor + " Period!";
        }, 5000);
    }

    $scope.$watch("editor", function editorListener() {

        var editor = $window.document.getElementById("editor");
        var start = editor.selectionStart;
        var end = editor.selectionEnd;

        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            editor.selectionStart = start;
            editor.selectionEnd = end;
        });

    });
});
```

Let say I start typing some text in textarea. Then I hit the button which will soon add " Period!" at the end of `$scope.editor` value. During the 5 seconds timeout I make focus on textarea again and write some more text. After 5 seconds my textarea value is updated.

I am watching for `$scope.editor` value. The `editorListener` will be executed on every `$digest` cycle. In this cycle also happens two-way data binding. I need to correct caret position right after data binding. Is `$scope.$evalAsync(...)` the right place where should I do this or not?

Comment: In most cases manipulating DOM from controller is a bad practice. It would be better to move the logic to a directive.

Comment: Just so you know, you may run into some issues with IE when using selectionStart, selecitonEnd. Check out this link: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?111407-Help-with-an-IE-workaround-to-find-selectionStart-and-selectionEnd-of-a-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Here is a directive I use to manipulate the caret position; however, like I stated in a comment, there is an issue with IE.

Below is something that may help you plan this out. One thing I noticed in your question is that you mention a condition where the user may re-focus the input box to type additional text, which I would believe resets the timeout; would this condition be true?

Instead of using a button to add text, would you rather just add it without? Like running the addSomeTextAtTheEnd function whenever a user un-focuses from the input box?

If you have to use the button, and a user re-focuses on the input box and types more into, you should cancel your button timeout.

Like:

```
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

    // Then clear the timeout in your $watch if there is any change to the input.
    clearTimeout(myVar);
```

If you do it this way, perhaps you will not even need to know the cursor position as the addSomeTextAtTheEnd function timeout will just reset on any input change before the 5 second timeout. If the 5 second timeout occurs then the addSomeTextAtTheEnd will run and "append text to the end" like it's supposed to do. Please give more information and I will update this as needed.

```
app.directive('filterElement', ['$filter', function($filter){

  return {
    restrict:'A', // Declares an Attributes Directive.
    require: '?ngModel', // ? checks for parent scope if one exists.

    link: function( scope, elem, attrs, ngModel ){
      if( !ngModel ){ return }

      var conditional = attrs.rsFilterElement.conditional ? attrs.rsFilterElement.conditional : null;

      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value){
        if( value == undefined || !attrs.rsFilterElement ){ return }

        // Initialize the following values
        // These values are used to set the cursor of the input.
        var initialCursorPosition = elem[0].selectionStart
        var initialValueLength = elem[0].value.length
        var difference = false

        // Sets ngModelView and ngViewValue
        ngModel.$setViewValue($filter( attrs.rsFilterElement )( value, conditional ));
        attrs.$$element[0].value = $filter( attrs.rsFilterElement )( value, conditional );

        if(elem[0].value.length > initialValueLength){ difference = true }
        if(elem[0].value.length < initialValueLength){ initialCursorPosition = initialCursorPosition - 1 }
        elem[0].selectionStart = difference ? elem[0].selectionStart : initialCursorPosition
        elem[0].selectionEnd = difference ? elem[0].selectionEnd : initialCursorPosition
      });
    } // end link
  } // end return
}]);
```